# How do you store user app data in .net core console app

Tags: console-application, dotnet-cli, .net-core

My scenario is I'm building a small cli app that I want to be able store user specific data in some kind of user local cache.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to the Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData path, but in dotnet core and cross platform friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly the same, but I solved it by storing the data in the application folder like so:

```cs
var userDataPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "userdata.json");
```

Of course you can also take a subfolder of `AppContext.BaseDirectory`.